# Existence of an analytic function, isolated essential singularity

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]From the characterization of essential singularities, the Laurent series expansion at the points z=n has infinitely many negative degree terms. Which tests guarantee the existence of an analytic function. Do I have  to use Hadamard factorization theorem to construct such a function or prove by contradiction ? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the formulation it is not clear if there should be such a singularity at every $n\in {\mathbb Z}$? But I guess it is the case since otherwise the function itself works fine. When you want it at every point then I think the following provides an affirmative answer:

Note that (the convergence here is not absolute):
$$h_0(z)=\pi \cot (\pi z)= \lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{|n|\leq N} \frac{1}{z-n}.$$ For $k\geq 1$:
$$ h_k(z) =  \left(\frac{d}{dz}\right)^k h_0(z) =  \lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{|n|\leq N} \frac{(-1)^k k!}{(z-n)^{k+1}}$$

Now, fix $z\in {\mathbb C}\setminus {\mathbb Z}$ and pick $0<r< \min_n |z-n|$. Then there is $C$ such that $\frac{1}{k!} |h_k(z)|\leq C r^k$   (because it is the Taylor coefficient of the powerseries for $h_0$ at $z$ and $h_0$ is analytic in a disk of radius bigger than $r$). Therefore,
$$  \sum_{k\geq 1} \left|\sum_{n\in {\mathbb Z}} \frac{1}{k^k (z-n)^k}\right| = \sum_{k\geq 1} \left| \frac{h_{k-1}(z)}{k! k^k} \right| \leq C \sum_{k\geq 1} \frac{kr^{k-1}}{k^k} < \infty. $$
(A more rigorous approach would be to take $h_0$ out of the sum since for $k=1$ the convergence is not absolute).

Thus $H(z)=\sum_{k\geq 1} \frac{1}{k^k k!} h_{k-1}(z)$ converges absolutely, whence is holomorphic in ${\mathbb C}\setminus{\mathbb Z}$ and has the prescribed essential singularities at $n\in {\mathbb Z}$.

Answer (score 0):

It suffices to consider the function
$$f(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^k(z-n)^k}$$
A sketch of proof to the convergence of this series:
$$\begin{align}
& \left|\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^k(z-n)^k}\right|\\
& \leq\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^k|z-n|^k}\\
& \approx\sum_{n\not=0}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^k\cdot n^k}\\
& = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\zeta(k)}{k^k} \leq\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\zeta(2)}{k^k}<\infty
\end{align}$$
A little modification of this computation leads to the uniform convergence in any compact subset in $\mathbb{C}\backslash\mathbb{Z}$.